# Creating array of objects in javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

Am new to JavaScript,I want to create an object of following structure

```
var result = {
         0: {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 },
         1: {'key3' : value3, 'key4' : value4 },
}
```

Someone please help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: This should work. http://jsfiddle.net/6nErP/

Comment: It may not work because you typed `Var`. Javascript is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is valid as well, but it creates an object. If you want to use an actual array, it could look like this:

```
var result = [
         {'key1' : value1, 'key2' : value2 },
         {'key3' : value3, 'key4' : value4 }
    ];
```

Note the change from `{}` to `[]` for the outer brackets and the drop of the top-level keys.

**Edit**

To create such an array dynamically, you can use something like this:

```
var result = []; // init empty array

result.push( {'key1' : value1, 'key2' : value2 } ); // insert a value

for( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
  result.push( {'key1' : i, 'key2' : i } ); // insert some more values in a loop
}
```

Comment: How do i create it dynamically?

Comment: @user2635299 That is totally dependent on your implementation and data source.

Answer (score 4):

The the object you posted is a JS map object,

```
var result = {
         0: {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 },
         1: {'key3' : value3, 'key4' : value4 }
}
```

You can access it like you access an associative array.

```
result[0][key1]
```

Or this way

```
result[0].key1
```

If you need an array of objects

```
  var result = [
  {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 },
  {'key3' : value3, 'key4' : value4 }
];
```

You can access it like previous example, and in this case you don't need to declare indexes.

**Updated:**

For map object creation you can also use a loop like @Sirko posted. The only difference is in the values assignation that could be done in this two ways:

```
var result  = {};
result[0] = {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 };
result.myOtherObj = {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 };
```

The map contents are the same as

```
var result = {
  0: {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 },
  myOtherObj: {'key1' : value1,'key2' : value2 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info

Comment: @jimva Can you tell how to create JS map object dynamically as well?

Comment: The creation of the object could be just as Sirko posted with a loop, the only difference is on the object assignation. I'm gonna edit the answer

Comment: @jimva Well explained.Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you could want to create dinamically it could be a solution:

```
var final_result = Array();
var element_1 = {"key1" : 2,"key2" : 3};
var element_2 = {"key3" : 2,"key4" : 3};

final_result.push(element_1);
final_result.push(element_2);
```